# Can't remove child entity using CRUD repository in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, crud-repository

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName ="";
    private String lastName;
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Order> orders;

    public void addOrder(Order order) {
        orders.add(order);
        order.setEmployee(this);
    }

    public void removeOrder(Order order) {
        orders.remove(order);
        order.setEmployee(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, employee.id)
                && Objects.equals(this.firstName, employee.firstName)
                && Objects.equals(this.lastName, employee.lastName)
                && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.role);
    }

    // Constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_ORDER")
class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String description;
    private Status status;

    @ManyToOne
    private Employee employee;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Order))
            return false;
        Order order = (Order) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, order.id) && Objects.equals(this.description, order.description)
                && this.status == order.status;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.description, this.status);
    }

    // Constructor, getters, setters
}
```

App code:

```
public static app() {
    ...
    Employee employee1 = new Employee("Bilbo", "Baggins", "burglar", new ArrayList<>());
    employeeRepository.save(employee1);
    
    Order order1 = new Order("Xiaomi", Status.IN_PROGRESS);
    orderRepository.save(order1);

    employee1.addOrder(order1);
    employeeRepository.save(employee1);
    employeeRepository.flush();
    orderRepository.flush();
    employee1.removeOrder(order1);
    employeeRepository.save(employee1);         
}
```

What am I facing is:

For `employee` table:

```
| id | first_name | last_name | role    |
| -- | ---------- | --------- | ------- |
| 1  | Bilbo      | Baggins   | burglar |
```

For `customer_order` table:

```
| id | description | status    | employee_id |
| -- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 1  | Xiaomi      | 0         | 1           |
```

So, I expected that after these strings execution

```
employee1.removeOrder(order1);
employeeRepository.save(employee1);
```

`order1` row will be deleted from database.
I think I need with some way to trigger `order1` entity saving. I played around and even after `order1` saving, it still remains in db with `employee_id` being `null`. I expected deleting of child, because I configured `orders` field as `orphanRemoval = true`.

My configs:

- java: 11
- hibernate: 5.4.32
- spring-boot: 2.5.3
- mysql: 8.0.26
- spring-data-jpa: 2.5.3
- hibernate-jpamodelgen: 5.4.32

Comment: Since the order is not in the array any more, spring doesn’t know that it has to update it, you should use the order repo to delete an order

Comment: @Chrys , so do I need trigger order and employee functions to delete child? Is there any way to do it with one single function like .deleteChildFromDB?

Answer (score 1):

The `employee1` will be detached after executing `employeeRepository.flush()`. You should change it's state to persistent.
Why you don't execute `employeeRepository.flush()` after the last line of code?

Comment: yea, I didn't understand the certain purpose of `.flash()` method in Spring Data JPA. I will review it.